# How do i add a Javascript object for a User control in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, microsoft-ajax

I have a User control and i have a method isDirty() added to this user control.
This user control is used in many places.

How do i access this method using javascript .How do i create a javascript object for this particular user control and then access it with the find method ?

The $find('__The id of the user control ') ?
I tried get null .???

Thanks & Regards,
Francis

Answer (score 0):

js object is created like this:

```
var myobject = { prop1: 'hello', 
               prop2: function(){//whatever}, 
              prop3:'yay'};

myobject.prop1; //'hello'
myobject.prop2(); //that's right, it runs that function(){//whatever} in prop2
```

You cannot access any server side methods with JS directly. Make an AJAX request with a JSON object, parse it in ASP.NET, and in ASP.NET, call your function you want based on what it says in the object.

Flash can use ExternalInterface.addCallback to do a direct JS access but I am not sure ASP.NET has such a thing (and I would strongly recommend against using a "Flash's blackbox JS access" style anyway).

If you already added a JS object to your user control somehow server side by executing javascript, you just access it like this:

```
myUserControlAssociatedJSObject.myFunction(); //it runs it!
```

Comment: Actually i want to access a Client side method say "IsDirty()" which is a part of the usercontrol using the $find component

Comment: if isDirty() is already there as a JS function in a JS object, (check in Firebug DOM maybe you can find it) then you just do wherevermyJsObjectIs.isDirty() and bam you can run the function - hope this helps